# Dropping duplicates in a pyarrow table?

Tags: pyarrow

Is there a way to sort data and drop duplicates using pure pyarrow tables? My goal is to retrieve the latest version of each ID based on the maximum update timestamp.

Some extra details: my datasets are normally structured into at least two versions:

- historical
- final

The historical dataset would include all updated items from a source so it is possible to have duplicates for a single ID for each change that happened to it (picture a Zendesk or ServiceNow ticket, for example, where a ticket can be updated many times)

I then read the historical dataset using filters, convert it into a pandas DF, sort the data, and then drop duplicates on some unique constraint columns.

```
dataset = ds.dataset(history, filesystem, partitioning)
table = dataset.to_table(filter=filter_expression, columns=columns)
df = table.to_pandas().sort_values(sort_columns, ascending=True).drop_duplicates(unique_constraint, keep="last")
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=df, schema=table.schema, preserve_index=False)

# ds.write_dataset(final, filesystem, partitioning)

# I tend to write the final dataset using the legacy dataset so I can make use of the partition_filename_cb - that way I can have one file per date_id. Our visualization tool connects to these files directly
# container/dataset/date_id=20210127/20210127.parquet

pq.write_to_dataset(final, filesystem, partition_cols=["date_id"], use_legacy_dataset=True, partition_filename_cb=lambda x: str(x[-1]).split(".")[0] + ".parquet")
```

It would be nice to cut out that conversion to pandas and then back to a table, if possible.

Comment: Dropping duplicates is not yet implemented in pyarrow. There is functionality to count values, and to filter, etc, so you might be able to do something custom based on those elements to achieve dropping duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit March 2022: PyArrow is adding more functionalities, though this one isn't here yet. My approach now would be:

```py
def drop_duplicates(table: pa.Table, column_name: str) -> pa.Table:
    unique_values = pc.unique(table[column_name])
    unique_indices = [pc.index(table[column_name], value).as_py() for value in unique_values]
    mask = np.full((len(table)), False)
    mask[unique_indices] = True
    return table.filter(mask=mask)
```

//end edit

I saw your question because I had a similar one, and I solved it for my work (due to IP issues I can't post the whole code but I'll try to answer as well as I can. I've never done this before)

```
import pyarrow.compute as pc
import pyarrow as pa
import numpy as np

array = table.column(column_name)
dicts = {dct['values']: dct['counts'] for dct in pc.value_counts(array).to_pylist()}
for key, value in dicts.items():
    # do stuff
```

I used the 'value_counts' to find the unique values and how many of them there are (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.value_counts.html). Then I iterated over those values. If the value was 1, I selected the row by using

```
mask = pa.array(np.array(array) == key)
row = table.filter(mask)
```

and if the count was more then 1 I selected either the first or last one by using numpy boolean arrays as a mask again.

After iterating it was just as simple as pa.concat_tables(tables)

warning: this is a slow process. If you need something quick&dirty, try the "Unique" option (also in the same link I provided).

**edit/extra:**: you can make it a bit faster/less memory intensive by keeping up a numpy array of boolean masks while iterating over the dictionary. then in the end you return a "table.filter(mask=boolean_mask)".
I don't know how to calculate the speed though...

**edit2:**
*(sorry for the many edits. I've been doing a lot of refactoring and trying to get it to work faster.)*

You can also try something like:

```py
def drop_duplicates(table: pa.Table, col_name: str) ->pa.Table:
    column_array = table.column(col_name)
    mask_x = np.full((table.shape[0]), False)
    _, mask_indices = np.unique(np.array(column_array), return_index=True)
    mask_x[mask_indices] = True
    return table.filter(mask=mask_x)
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI I happened to stumble upon this library that had a drop_duplicates function (and a few other things) that I used as guide.
https://github.com/TomScheffers/pyarrow_ops/blob/main/pyarrow_ops/ops.py

Comment: This works fine until your dataset goes beyond 200M rows. Performance is slow with large dataset

Comment: @rewreu correct! It's not the best solution. In my work we use it with a cache I believe, but we literally yesterday thought 'can't this get quicker with one of pyarrows newest version?' So I'll post a better solution when we have found one :)

Comment: Would be interesting to see a benchmark between this method and OPs method of converting to pandas and using `df.drop_duplicates()`.

Answer (score 1):

The following gives a good performance. About **2mins** for a table with **half billion rows**. The reason I don't do `combine_chunks()`: there is a bug, arrow seems can not combine chunk arrays if there size are too large. See details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10172?src=confmacro

```
a = [len(tb3['ID'].chunk(i)) for i in range(len(tb3['ID'].chunks))]
c = np.array([np.arange(x) for x in a])
a = ([0]+a)[:-1]
c = pa.chunked_array(c+np.cumsum(a))

    
tb3= tb3.set_column(tb3.shape[1], 'index', c)
selector = tb3.group_by(['ID']).aggregate([("index", "min")])
    
tb3 = tb3.filter(pc.is_in(tb3['index'], value_set=selector['index_min']))
```

I found duckdb can give better performance on group by. Change the last 2 lines above into the following will give 2X speedup:

```
import duckdb 
duck = duckdb.connect()
sql = "select first(index) as idx from tb3 group by ID"
duck_res = duck.execute(sql).fetch_arrow_table()
tb3 = tb3.filter(pc.is_in(tb3['index'], value_set=duck_res['idx']))
```

Comment: This seems the fastest answer. Another thing may increase speed: use the dictionaary encoding

Comment: What about using duckdb entirely for this? You can query partitioned datasets, and your query could include select distinct on () in order to remove duplicates from the results.